# IFrame Request with SessionID and Response of Secure Session Token

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, session, iframe

I have never dealt with session handling to this detail before. And I am stuck.

Request
POST:

URL : blablabla.com

Content: ?UserName=blabla&Password=DingDong&CustNumber=11233&SessionId=qeqt5o0lsa0zbdhehnqy31om

Response

So as you can see I am requesting with a username, password and sessionid. The response will be some secure token. I have the ability to pass in the SST into the request string as well. I also have tried that and have the same error.

The session that I pass in is just a randomly generated ShortGuid. I have added that to Session.Add() and also tried the SessionIDManager approach. I have no idea what I am doing wrong, Is there perhaps some standard approach with IFrame and session passing and handling? Is there a thing like a "Valid" sessionId based on some Session Standard?

Any ideas or suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing the implementation method. Have no idea why this works and the other method does not work.

```
ShortGuid sessionID = ShortGuid.NewGuid ();
Session.Add (sessionID.ToString (), "asdasdasdasd");
string encodedURL = Convert.ToBase64String (Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery));  

WebClient client = new WebClient ();
NameValueCollection data = new NameValueCollection ();

data.Add ("UserName", "asdasd");
data.Add ("Password", "asdasd");
data.Add ("CustNumber", "asdasdasd");
data.Add ("Amount", "21231313");
data.Add ("SessionId", sessionID.ToString ());
data.Add ("UserDeclinedURL", encodedURL);
data.Add ("UserApprovedURL", encodedURL);
data.Add ("ServerURL", encodedURL);


string response = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString (client.UploadValues ("URL", data));
```